# wordpress theme excerpt function elimination-thao studios theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the excerpt function or render it functionless as i want all posts to be viewed in full of its content. I think the theme has some tracking to make sure the excerption is in that line, so it must exist.

```
function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
      if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
      array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}

function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}
```

I only have these 2 lines of codes which i know is related.
I dont know where the $limit come from, i tried to find on all theme related php,no findings.
Please help me. Thank you very muc.

Comment: Do you want to show full content instead of the excerpt in your theme ?

Comment: Yes!if possible. I was trying to make the excerpt as long as possible so it will show full, but fail

Comment: Why don't you use the_content() in the theme ?

Comment: Please show how. I see the the_content in 2nd func,reli noob with wordpress..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just find your template file (could be index.php) where you want to display the full content instead of excerpted content and replace the function `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()` inside the loop, i.e.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
           <!-- do other stuff ... -->
            the_content();
           <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

About [**the_content()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) and the [**loop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: yes thank you, i appreciate you gave me the extra function, but i just want to show the whole content, so i just replace the excerpt with content, thanks a lot for the tips :)